# Postgresql+Node.js queries start failing after a few tries

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku

I have a node.js app with a postgresql database running on Heroku and for some reason `select` functions seem to break and start failing after many successful attempts for what seems to be no reason at all..

Example code:

```
pg.connect(database_url, function(err, client) {
    if(client) {
        var date = new Date();
        var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM accounts',function(err, result) {
            if(!err) {
                res.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
                accounts = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
            } else {
                res.send('failed');
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

The above code works perfectly about 10 times and then out of nowhere seems to break.

How can i remedy this issue?

Comment: @muistooshort I get a heroku message that says something like 'page not responindg' ( essentially a 500 Internal Error )

Comment: Did you look at your logs? `heroku logs`

Comment: @JonMountjoy yeah it simply says that there was a 'Request Timeout' with an error code `H12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works 10 times, and fails on the 11'th then it's probably because the pool of connections has run out.

You should call `done` in your code after you have finished with the request, to send the database connection back to the pool.

```
pg.connect(database_url, function(err, client, done) {
    if(client) {
        var date = new Date();
        var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM accounts',function(err, result) {
            if(!err) {
                res.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
                accounts = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
            } else {
                res.send('failed');
            }
            done(); // call done to close the conection
        });
    } else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

see [the documentation for `connect`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/pg#wiki-method-connect)

Comment: I actually got to this solution myself a while back but i forgot about the question, thanks anyway though :)